# How to initialize omnifaces manually to avoid omnifaces.GenericEnumConverter not found?

Tags: jsf, converters, jsf-2.2, omnifaces

I changed my web.xml from `metadata-complete="false"` to `metadata-complete="true"` and I got the following error:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: Expression Error: omnifaces.GenericEnumConverter not found.
```

I'm using tomcat 8.0.24, jsf mojarra 2.2.12, primefaces 5.2 and omnifaces 1.11.

Is it possible to initialize omnifaces manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicitly register it as below in webapp's own `faces-config.xml`.

```
<converter>
    <converter-id>omnifaces.GenericEnumConverter</converter-id>
    <converter-class>org.omnifaces.converter.GenericEnumConverter</converter-class>
</converter>
```

Comment: I repackaged omnifaces-1.11.jar and included META-INF/web-fragment.xml from omnifaces-2.1.jar. In this case, I don´t need to change my webapp´s own faces-config.xml.